# command output based on pattern

Tags: bash

Consider I have a command with some pattern, for example:

```
$ grep "some string" file-[0-99]
```

how can I write result into a file that will have its name based on the current value of a pattern, so that

```
$ grep "some string" file-0 > processed-0
$ grep "some string" file-1 > processed-1
...
```

Something like `$ grep "some string" file-[0-100] > processed-[0-100]` though this one doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[0-99]` is the same as `[0-9]`, `[0-100]` means `[01]`. `[...]` defines a character class, you can't use longer strings there.

To solve your original question, you can use a loop:

```
for i in {0..99} ; do
    grep "some string" file-"$i" > processed-"$i"
done
```

Or, if not all the possible input files exist, you can extract the suffix from the file name:

```
for file in file-* ; do
    suffix=${file##*-}
    grep "some string" "$file" > processed-"$suffix"
done
```

Comment: Works great, thanx